# How to find a particular file id of google drive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

In this code, I am finding a particular folder Id against its name. But I want to find a particular file id against its name. How to do it?

```
def findId(self, filename):
    page_token = None
    while True:
        response = self.service.files().list(q="name = '"+ filename +"' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
                                                  spaces='drive',
                                                  fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                                  pageToken=page_token).execute()
        for file in response.get('files', []):
            print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if page_token is None:
            break
```

Comment: so you want to search for a file in your drive account?  Do you know what type the file is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at how the q parameter for the file.list method actually works.  This opitno lets you search on a lot of things, name is just one of them.

The first thing to remember is everything in Google drive is a file and it has a fileid. So your current search is searching for files with the name of filename and the internal google drive mime type of folder.

```
name = '"+ filename +"' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
```

You could then switch this to just search after name which would then return all the files with any mimetype that match that name.

```
name = '"+ filename +"'"
```

You will then get a list back of all the files that match that name, the problem then being if you have more the one file on your drive account matching that name.

```
def findId(self, filename):
    page_token = None
    while True:
        response = self.service.files().list(q="name = '"+ filename +"'",
                                                  spaces='drive',
                                                  fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                                  pageToken=page_token).execute()
        for file in response.get('files', []):
            print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if page_token is None:
            break
```

There is some documentation you might find interesting that goes into detail which options you can send with Q parameter [search files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-files)
I also have a video which explains it [Google drive API V3: Beginners to listing files and searching files](https://youtu.be/pHOweM1Gl6c)  you may find the explantation helpful, the code itself is in C#.